# Why doesn't a local Angular2 app run just by opening index.html solely?

Tags: angular

I'm studying Angular2 and created a local project folder using `ng new myproject`, `cd myproject` and `ng serve`. Then I could open the file with the address of localhost:4200.

But when I open the index.html file only, it just shows *loading...*. and *app works!* does not show up.

What happens to `index.html` when `ng server` is called? And does it work in the same way when the project file is on the Web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happend to index.html is that the cli adds a bunch of javascript imports to it, specifically bundles created by the cli. You can see this by inspecting the source when you run your angular app.

When you want to deploy it on the web, you have to pre build it. In essence, run an `ng build --prod`, it should create a 'dist' folder that you can deploy on your preferred web server.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the command you gave and works on the server well.